# Customize source parameter Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, url, redirect, parameter

I have to customize the returning from saving and exiting (by canel) a list element. I know that is done by the source parameter in the url, but I did not understand how to set/edit it. 
If I take a look to my source code I see the following anchor:

```
<a id="idHomePageNewItem" class="ms-heroCommandLink" href="http://portal/projects/buchungsportal/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId=%7BA57192AA%2D80F8%2D4C4E%2D91DA%2D94131DCC2F47%7D&amp;RootFolder=&amp;BetriebId=1265" 
    data-viewctr="6" onclick="NewItem2(event, &quot;http://portal/projects/buchungsportal/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=8&amp;ListId=%7BA57192AA%2D80F8%2D4C4E%2D91DA%2D94131DCC2F47%7D&amp;RootFolder=&amp;BetriebId=1265&quot;); 
    return false;" target="_self" title="Ein neues Element zu dieser Liste oder Bibliothek hinzufügen.">
    <span class="ms-list-addnew-imgSpan16"><img id="idHomePageNewItem-img" 
        src="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/982A91AA/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=6" class="ms-list-addnew-img16">
    </span>
    <span>Neues Element</span>
</a>
```

When I click on my anchor the following url opens:

```
http://portal/projects/buchungsportal/Lists/Anfragen/NewForm.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fportal%2Fprojects%2Fbuchungsportal%2FLists%2FBetriebe%2FAllItems%2Easpx&RootFolder=&BetriebId=1265
```

Where does the source parameter come from? How can I customize it before sending the request to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you will have to create custom New/Edit forms for list items and will have to create custom buttons as below:

```
<td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">

<input type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript:{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={put your url here} ')}" />

</td>
```

similarly for cancel button:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" name="btnCancel" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__redirect={/}')}" style="width: 101px" />
```

Comment: The custom forms are already written, but I can't adopt your solution, since I come to my form from different pages and i need to have different returning pages.

Comment: @Emaborsa: then you can follow JS approach suggested in below blog. I haven't tried this but i think it should work https://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/custom-redirect-after-creating-a-new-sharepoint-item/

Comment: I already have read this post, but it does't explain how to it `Via URL Parameter`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this multiple ways by modifying the Save button or the Redirect url but all of them cause other problems with the form, such as not validating fields.

I finally decided to check the Source parameter on open and if it's not right then set it and reload the page.  **Call this before document.ready for better performance.**

```
function CheckSourceParameter(){
//GOAL: We always need to open a request with the right ?Source= parameter so we can launch the right page on save
//Check the param here and if it's not correct then recreate the url and reload the page


    var validSource = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/SitePages/ThankYou.aspx';
    validSource = encodeURI(validSource);

    //get initial Source param, need encoded value
    var orgURL = document.location.toString();
    var orgSource = GetUrlKeyValue('Source', true, orgURL, true);

    //alert(orgSource + '\n\n' + validSource );

    //does the Source param match what we want; both values should be encoded before testing
    if(orgSource == validSource){
        //the Source param matches our desired url, nothing else to do here
        return; 
    };

    //the Source param doesn't match, need to update and reopen
    if(IsBlank(orgSource)){

        //just append the validSource to the url
        var newURL = orgURL + "?Source=" + validSource;

    }else{

        //need to replace the value in the url; both values must be decoded here
        var newURL = orgURL.replace(orgSource.toString(), validSource);
    };

    //alert(orgURL + '\n\n' + newURL);

    //reopen this form with the right Source param
    document.location = newURL;
};
```

`IsBlank()` is another custom function I wrote, but you just need to check if the `value == '';`

**NOTE: You'll need to change your Cancel buttons or they'll open the ThankYou page too.**